# Transaction hash on a degree certifiate

Tags: hash

About a week ago I completed an online course from a reputed university. When I got the certificate, at the bottom I noticed a 'Blockchain Hash' followed by a long string of characters. When I clicked on it, it took me to a 'transaction details page'. My question is why is this here? Is this to authenticate the certificate?

Comment: Wow which university is this exactly?

Comment: Can you share a photo and a link to the transaction? This is super interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Blockchain is an Distributed Immutable Ledger meaning that once a data is stored in a blockchain it remains in the blockchain as long as it exists. So, it can not be deleted nor can it be changed.

With the hash provided to you, it seems that the hash(Probably SHA256) was generated with your certificate as the input. One of the hashing property is it is collision free i.e. each Hash is unique in its nature. So, if you change even a single character on your certificate the hash will change.

So my observation is by using blockchain and hashing property, the certificate provider is giving you an optimal and ever-lasting proof that you have indeed completed your course and if someone asks for its validation you can simply generate the hash through the used Algorithm(probably SHA256) and tell them please verify it by looking in the blockchain. And they have to believe it because blockchain again is Imutable and Unchangeable Ledger.